# How to create a pyramid in CSS, HTML and Vue3?

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

I already have a dynamically created pyramid. and it look like this (this is a `state.pyramidlevel = 3`) because it has 3 layers:

[image]

with the following code:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">
   <div id="zoomable" class="">
      <div v-html.domProps="state.pyramid" style="width: max-content; height: 100vh;"></div>
   </div>
</div>


function createPyramid() {

    const height = state.pyramidlevel;

    let pyramidstr = '';

    // Start with 1 asterisk in the first row
    let numAsterisks = 2;

    for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        let rowStr = '';

        // Add spaces to center the pyramid
        for (let space = 0; space < height - row - 1; space++) {
            rowStr += '';
        }

        // Add div for this row
        for (let star = 0; star < numAsterisks; star++) {
            rowStr += `
            <div 
            style="
                text-align:center;
                margin:3px; 
                width: 150px; 
                height: 30px; 
                border: 1px solid black; 
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

                Vacant
            </div>`;
        }

        // Add this row to the pyramid
        pyramidstr += `<div
        
        style="
            display: flex; 
            place-content: center;
        "
        
        >${rowStr}</div>`;

        // Double the number of asterisks for the next row
        numAsterisks *= 2;
    }

    state.pyramid = pyramidstr;

}
```

Now, this is where my head hurts:

I want my pyramid to be, 1:2, which means, every brick should be in the middle of every 2 brick below: just like this for a `state.pyramidlevel = 2`:

```
     .____.            .____.
     |____|            |____|
.____.    .____.   .____.  .____.
|____|    |____|   |____|  |____|
```

And so on.....

I really need help. been working on this 3 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this works when you double the blocks at each level, since the blocks quickly get too far away from each other to be perceived as stacked, i.e.

```
       o               o
   o       o       o       o
 o   o   o   o   o   o   o   o
o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o
```

It's more like two pyramids already. Imagine adding two more levels...

Simple stacking is easy though:

```js
function createPyramid(height) {
  let pyramidstr = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    pyramidstr.push('<div class="pyramid-level">')
    
    for (let star = 0; star < row + 1; star++) {
      pyramidstr.push(`<div class="pyramid-block"></div>`);
    }
    pyramidstr.push(`</div>`);
  }
  return pyramidstr.join('');
}

document.getElementById('pyramid-root').innerHTML = createPyramid(4)
```

```css
.pyramid-level {
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
}

.pyramid-block {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="pyramid-root"></div>
```

Because of the way it grows, you can use simple horizontal margins to adjust the space between the blocks.

With doubling row size, space grows exponentially. Using containers seems easier to me:

```js
function createPyramid(height) {
  let pyramidstr = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    pyramidstr.push('<div class="pyramid-level">')
    const blockWidth = (1 << (height - row - 1)) * 20;
    for (let star = 0; star < 1<<(row+1); star++) {
      pyramidstr.push(`
          <div class="pyramid-block-container" style="width: ${blockWidth}px">
            <div class="pyramid-block"></div>
          </div>`
      );
    }
    pyramidstr.push(`</div>`);
  }
  return pyramidstr.join('');
}

document.getElementById('pyramid-root').innerHTML = createPyramid(4)
```

```css
.pyramid-level {
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
}

.pyramid-block {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: purple;
}
.pyramid-block-container{
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="pyramid-root"></div>
```

As expected, looks wonky, right?

That was fun, hope it helps.

Comment: You know what? You're the BEST! :D

Comment: Question, I tried to rewrite it in vuejs3 and it apprears differently. why?

Comment: I can only guess from your code above, but most likely, the CSS classes are not applied to the content of `v-html`. You can check that in the console. If so, you can try using [deep selectors](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors), i.e. `* :deep(.pyramid-level)`.